# How to output Concrete as an outline font in math mode with Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, eulervm, euler

The following MWE, when processed with `pdflatex` in TeX Live 2014, outputs an equation with a 'w' in Computer Concrete.  (I assume this is an outline font since it can be scaled without jaggy stuff by a PDF viewer.)  The Greek letter is in Euler.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Note the following:
  \[
  \mathfrak F, w \Vdash \phi \iff \mathfrak F \models \alpha(w).
  \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This suprised me a lot since I've been assuming we don't have freely available vectorized Concrete for math-mode.  Without the package `eulervm`, this would result in a jagged bitmap font, as expected.

My question is whether or not I can output other kinds of smooth letters (Greek letters, math symbols, etc.) in Concrete in math-mode and, if I can, how.

EDIT: The screenshot below shows the 'w' I assumed was in Concrete.  Also, let me add that the TeX Live 2014 I use is from Fedora 21's repository.

[image]

Comment: For math symbols use \usepackage{amssymb}. Package documentation : http://estudijas.lu.lv/pluginfile.php/14809/mod_page/content/16/instrukcijas/matematika_moodle/LaTeX_Symbols.pdf

Comment: It is using **cm-super** which apparently includes some conversions of Concrete as well as Computer Modern.

Comment: Off-topic: you know that Fedora 21 is no longer supported and will no longer get security updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you can't. There are no Greek or specialist maths symbols available from Concrete in type1 format. The rest of this answer is a (hopefully) explanatory narrative.

I did not realise, but apparently **cm-super** includes conversions not only of Computer Modern but also of some other fonts, including Concrete.

When you load `ccfonts.sty`, part of what happens is this:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont  {operators}   {OT1}{ccr} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont  {letters}     {OML}{ccm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont  {symbols}     {OMS}{ccsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont  {largesymbols}{OMX}{ccex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}     {OT1}{ccr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}     {OT1}{ccr} {m}{it}
```

When you load `eulervm.sty`, this happens:

```
\edef\operator@encoding{\encodingdefault}
```

This defines an encoding which is then used to declare various fonts, including maths alphabets etc. These definitions override those from `ccfonts.sty`. For example, `eulervm.sty` includes this:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}  {\operator@encoding}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}
```

By default, the encoding will be OT1. However, if you've written

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

then the default encoding is T1. This means that the **cm-super** type1 replacements are used in place of the Concrete metafonts because the latter are not available in the T1 encoding. This is just the same as the **cm-super** type1 Computer Modern replacing the OT1 metafonts for text when T1 is used.

The upshot of all this is that you end up with fonts from **cm-super** replacing those originally loaded by `ccfonts.sty`, where possible and except where `eulervm.sty` overwrites the definitions more explicitly.

So what else might **cm-super** provide?

Here is the full list of matches for `Concrete` in the fonts provided by **cm-super**:

```
sfocc10
sform10
sform5
sform6
sform7
sform8
sform9
sfosl10
sfosl5
sfosl6
sfosl7
sfosl8
sfosl9
sfoti10
```

[Output from `zgrep -l Concrete fonts/afm/public/cm-super/* | sed 's/^.*\///' | sed 's/\..*$//'`.]

Mostly these are size variations, of course. The distinct shapes, families etc. available are, therefore, these

```
sfocc10.afm.gz:FullName Computer Modern Concrete Caps and Small Caps
sform10.afm.gz:FullName Computer Modern Concrete Roman
sfosl10.afm.gz:FullName Computer Modern Concrete Slanted
sfoti10.afm.gz:FullName Computer Modern Concrete Italic
```

[Output from `zgrep Concrete fonts/afm/public/cm-super/{sfocc10,sform10,sfosl10,sfoti10}.afm.gz | sed 's/^.*\///' | grep Full`.]

As can be seen, this does not include any maths fonts *per se*. There are some text fonts which can be used for things like `operators` in maths mode or for `\mathit` or whatever. But there are no maths symbol fonts, so no Greek or specialist symbols available.

Answer (score 1):

You were getting some of the upright letters from the text font in math mode because you loaded the `serif` font theme without `professionalfonts`.  This tries to replace Latin letters in math mode with the Roman font.

If you wanted to stick to Type 1 fonts, you could use `mathastext` to load Concrete for digits and Latin letters, and GFS Neohellenic, which is also an upright slab serif, as the Greek font.  If you really wanted Type 1 Concrete text and Euler math fonts, you can load `\usefonttheme{serif}` followed by `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` and load your font packages normally.

The way to do what you requested is to load the OpenType font CMU Concrete, which contains Greek letters.  You can do this with either `unicode-math`, `mathastext`, or `mathspec`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont{CMU Concrete Roman}[range=up]
\setmathfont{CMU Concrete Bold}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{CMU Concrete Italic}[range=it]
\setmathfont{CMU Concrete Bold Italic}[range=bfit]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Note the following:
  \[
  \mathfrak F, w \Vdash \varphi \iff \mathfrak F \models \alpha(w).
  \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Concrete sample]

The above loads all letters and digits from CMU Concrete, as many symbols as possible from [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf), and uses Libertinus Math as the fallback font for any symbols that are left.

I made one slight change: CMU Concrete contains `\varphi` but not `\phi`.

Note that DEK originally commissioned Euler to replace Concrete in math mode, for his book *Concrete Mathematics*.  That is, AMS Euler exists precisely so his equations would **not** look like this.